# How to filter a Lambda expression from possible Querystrings in C#

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm trying to filter results via a query string but not sure of the best way to do this, what i have so far is:

```
var topic = Request.QueryString["topic"];
var date = Request.QueryString["date"];
var keyword = Request.QueryString["keyword"];

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(topic) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(date) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyword))
{
    items = root.Children().Where(x => x.IsDocumentType("Event-Item") &&
        x.GetPropertyValue("eventTitle").ToString().Contains(topic) || 
        x.GetPropertyValue("eventDates").ToString().Contains(date) || 
        x.GetPropertyValue("eventSummary").ToString().Contains(keyword)).OrderByDescending(x => x.CreateDate).ToList();
}
else
{
    items = root.Children().Where(x => x.IsDocumentType("Event-Item")).OrderByDescending(x => x.CreateDate).ToList();
}
```

Does this look correct? Is there a better(more correct) way of doing this?
Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unrelated to an answer: You should put `()`'s in the where lambda to indicate whether `Event-Item` is required (with any one of the other three) or whether the `Event-Item` and `eventTitle` pair is required or either of the other two.

Comment: More related to an answer, check out [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)

Comment: Why if `topic` is empty and `date` is not empty you still filter by `topic`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about conditional `where` for each term?

```
string topic = Request.QueryString["topic"];
string date = Request.QueryString["date"];
string keyword = Request.QueryString["keyword"];

var filteredItems = root.Children()
                        .Where(x => x.IsDocumentType("Event-Item"));
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(topic))
    filteredItems = filteredItems.Where(x => x.GetPropertyValue("eventTitle")
                                              .ToString()
                                              .Contains(topic));
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(date))
    filteredItems = filteredItems.Where(x => x.GetPropertyValue("eventDates")
                                              .ToString()
                                              .Contains(date));
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyword))
    filteredItems = filteredItems.Where(x => x.GetPropertyValue("eventSummary")
                                              .ToString()
                                              .Contains(keyword));
items = filteredItems.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreateDate).ToList();
```

Comment: would this still work if date and keyword were supplied and not topic? or if topic and keyword were supplied but not date? as these are filter params

Comment: Yes, it will. If only date and keyword are supplied, then the filtering is performed only on them (no filtering on topic). If none of parameters is supplied, then no filtering is performed at all.

Comment: Just tested and it works great, thank you for your help, much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I would break it down as follows.  You are always filtering on "Event-Item", so take that out of the if/else and do it first.  Then check for nulls and filter if needed.  Finally, since you are always sorting, do that after everything.

```
    var topic = Request.QueryString["topic"];
    var date = Request.QueryString["date"];
    var keyword = Request.QueryString["keyword"];

    items = root
              .Children()
              .Where(x => x.IsDocumentType("Event-Item"));

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(topic) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(date) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyword))
    {
        items = items.Where(x =>                    
            x.GetPropertyValue("eventTitle").ToString().Contains(topic) || 
            x.GetPropertyValue("eventDates").ToString().Contains(date) || 
            x.GetPropertyValue("eventSummary").ToString().Contains(keyword));
    }

    items = items.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreateDate);
```